# How to calculate a frequency curve from a sample of values, and interpolate between curves

Tags: statistics, interpolation

I have a set of about 500 values, from which I'm currently plotting a histogram.

I'd like to plot a frequency curve, i.e. go from the left two graphs to the rightmost on the below image [borrowed from Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrequencyCurve.html).

[image: Frequency curve]

If I can manage this, I'll then have frequency curves for various points in time. I'd like to smoothly interpolate between them.

i.e. if I have a frequency curve at 1 month, another at 3 and another at 6, I'd like a function that accepts a range and a time, and returns the approximate frequency of that range at that point in time.

I don't really know where to begin with this. Any pointers on what I should read up on to accomplish this? And any ideas as to how can I go about doing it?

**Edit**

By "maintain the peak throughout" I mean that interpolating between two curves like these two:
[image: 1/(E^(x^2/2) Sqrt[2 Pi])]
[image: 1/(E^((-5 + x)^2/2) Sqrt[2 Pi])]

Should not result halfway in a curve that looks like this:
[image: ((1/(E^(x^2/2) Sqrt[2 Pi])) + (1/(E^((-5 + x)^2/2) Sqrt[2 Pi])))/2]

But should look like this:
[image: 1/(E^((-2.5 + x)^2/2) Sqrt[2 Pi])]

Comment: What you are looking for is kernel density estimation. This can be done with any reasonable statistics software.

Comment: @Nameless Thanks very much for the pointer. Any recommendations for how to create a smooth interpolation that maintains the peak throughout?

Comment: What do you mean "maintain the peak throughout"?

Comment: @Nameless I've edited the question with graphs to clarify

Comment: Yes, you can do that with kernel density estimation. It depends on the bandwidth whether two peaks are summarized in one (large bandwidth), or whether they remain (smaller bandwidth).